# Some clues to improve my EE.SE questions?

Tags: discussion

Good morning.

Could you give some clues so I can improve my questions, to get off my EE.SE ban? I've read some articles in help further I am trying my best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ban on the meta account, there is on you EE.SE account. You'll have to improve the quality of your existing questions or wait until the ban wears off.

You can post questions on the main site, make sure they are on-topic:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

And many others:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Cool. I've read 
"You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account." and I thought I was ban.
But, how to get rid of "You have reached your question limit" message?

Comment: You either have to edit your bad questions or wait 6 months